# Use variable from Activity in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've made an AsyncTask that changes the device wallpaper using a bitmap from a file, but I have multiple different buttons that need to do the same thing (change the wallpaper from a file) but with a different filename for each (to use as the wallpaper) for each button.

So can include something in the code that starts the AsyncTask that tells it which file to look for which would be different for each button.

I'm pretty new to this so any help is appreciated.

One of the buttons:

```
    Button setwallpaper1button = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.setwallpaper1button);
    setwallpaper1button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Directory/Wallpaper_1.jpg").exists()) {
                Snackbar.make(myView, "Please Download Wallpaper First.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                new SetWallpaperTask(getActivity()).execute( // I think something needs to go here // );
            }
        }
    });
```

From AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Directory/" + "// This is where the variable thats different for each button needs to go //");
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: You need to have some sort of data sets of Filenames like `List<String> filenames ....` then each button will have a dedicated index so that you can obtain the filename from your data sets when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to map the resource to the buttons on the screen. Lets assume that you have three buttons on the screen.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
     String imageName = "Wallpaper_1.jpg";
        if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Directory/"+imageName ).exists()) {
            Snackbar.make(myView, "Please Download Wallpaper First.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
        else { 
            new SetWallpaperTask(getActivity()).execute( imageName  ); 
        } 
    } 
}); 

 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
     String imageName = "Wallpaper_2.jpg";
        if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Directory/"+imageName).exists()) {
            Snackbar.make(myView, "Please Download Wallpaper First.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
        else { 
            new SetWallpaperTask(getActivity()).execute( imageName  ); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

And then in your asynctask's doInBackground

```
@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    bmImg = 
 BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Directory/" + args[0]);
return null; 
}
```